# Not able to perform operation on tooltip through Appium Android

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, tooltip, appium

I am trying to automate android application with Appium. I have to perform click operation on tooltip but appium does not identify the tooltip. I have attached screenshot below in which i have to perform click event on "Margaritaville-Grand Turk" but i am not able to perform this operation. How way we can perform action on tooltip.[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Appium, and mobile automation, but I could guess that tooltip is could not be found in activity structure (you could check with Appium inspector, or UIAutomatorViewer), same problem with toast notifications and `AutocompleteTextView`. I solve this with OCR image recognition engine.

Here you can find my implementation in Ruby: [gist](https://gist.github.com/brbrr/7a97e1b9b8394421e34f)

I use 2 OCR libs, because of limitation for both:

- '[rtesseract](https://github.com/dannnylo/rtesseract)' can't find text coordinates
- '[tesseract](https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr)' have problems with text recognition

Idea is simple:

1. get required screen state(i.e. tooltip is shown)
2. make screenshot or few
3. process these screenshots, and look for required text
4. get text coordinates, and click on it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I have performed tap action through X-Y Coordinate.

Comment: @RohitDoraya You can accept my answer, if you think it fits.